# How can I hook things up so AngularJS will populate the page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, controllers

I have something that should be showing a lot of data that is not showing any data.

In my HTML I have:

```
<div ng-controller='OutputController'>
    <div ng-repeat='user in data.users'>
        <div ng-repeat='monologue in data.monologues[user]'>
            <span class='text' ng-bind='monologue.text'></span>
            <span class='timestamp' ng-bind='new Date(monologue.timestamp).toLocaleString()'></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In my JavaScript I have:

```
var repeatEr = function(data, status, headers, config)
{
    var interval = 1000;
    angular.extend($scope, data);
```

In the data being sent to my page I have:

`{"monologues": {"jonathan.hayward@pobox.com": [["False", 0.0], ["False", 0.0], ["False", 0.0], ["False", 0.0], ["False", 0.0], ["False", 0.0], ["False", 0.0], ["False", 0.0], ... }, "users": ["jonathan.hayward@pobox.com"]}`

What is happening is that it is displaying empty results.

What I intend for it to do is to pull the Ajax data it is pulling, and then display the text ("False" here) and timestamps in successive DIV's. (But I'm not focused on the timestamp now, just the text.)

Given the data as I have it, what should I be doing with the repeaters so that it is displaying results accordingly?

--Or--

Given the repeaters I have, what should I be populating as data so that the repeaters will have what they need?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat expects that you'll be iterating an Array. Your data.monologues is a single complex object, hence why it's not showing any data.

In order to make your code to work, you'll need to make your data.monologues an array of complex objects.

```
      [{"monologues": {... etc etc ...}}]
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought that data.monologues[user] would be [["False", 0.0], ["False", 0.0], ...]. Are you saying that I should have data be an array of dictionaries mapping monologues to an array then?

Comment: I'm saying that data should be an Array of Monologue objects.

Answer (score 0):

I had:

```
<div ng-controller='OutputController'>
    <div ng-repeat='user in data.users'>
        <div ng-repeat='monologue in data.monologues[user]'>
            <span class='text' ng-bind='monologue.text'></span>
            <span class='timestamp' ng-bind='new Date(monologue.timestamp).toLocaleString()'></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem was the '**data.**' - it worked much better with:

```
<div ng-controller='OutputController'>
    <div ng-repeat='user in users'>
        <div ng-repeat='monologue in monologues[user]'>
            <span class='text' ng-bind='monologue.text'></span>
            <span class='timestamp' ng-bind='new Date(monologue.timestamp).toLocaleString()'></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```